# exportar e importar variables en javascript

Tags: javascript

quiero pasar una variable de mi archivo **expor.js** a **main.js** intente con `export` pero no funciona

```
 -------expor.js-------
    export const k=13;

 --------main.js------
 import k from "expor.js"
```

me lanza el siguiente error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` y en la importacion

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error puede deberse al llamar al archivo JavaScript en las etiquetas html

se tiene que declarar el atributo `type` dentro del tag script

`<scritp type="module" src="main"></script>`

Ya en el archivo lo mandar a llamar.

```
// main.js
import { k } from './export.js';
window.onload = ()=>{
    document.write(k);
}
```

Puedes importar la constantes separándola, así tienes la posibilidad de exportar mas variables.

```
// export.js
const K = 13; 
export {k};
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, tal vez convendría enlazar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/M%C3%B3dulos) como referencia para cualquier duda adicional.